# Javascript - Efficient way of defining a tree of images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Basically I have a folder full of images that branch out.

E.G:

```
Character
__male
____plain
______white
______brown
______black
____suit
______white
______brown
______black
__female
____plain
______white
______brown
______black
____dress
______white
______brown
______black
____bathingSuit
______white
______brown
______black
```

I want to end up using the `drawImage` function like so:

```
var gender = "male",
    color = "white",
    clothing = "plain";

ctx.drawImage(character[gender][clothing][color], 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

How would I go about doing this in a neat way that doesn't require 100 lines of code?

Also, the folder of images is ever so expanding. Is there a way where the code can automatically "go through folders" and add the images instead of manually adding it to the code?

Comment: You could use a function and pass those variables values as the function arguments, or you can read the values from some HTML field, depends on your application logic. Not sure about what you miss here, could you explain better your issue?

Comment: I think passing it to a function like gyre explained wouldn't be very friendly to the CPU since its for a game, and there will be lots of mutations

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate your logic inside a function, and use string concatenation when setting the correct image `src`. Assuming your `Character` folder is in the same directory as your HTML file, you can use:

```js
// Placeholder variable
var ctx = { drawImage: Function.prototype }


var imageCache = {}

function getCharacterImage(options) {
  var src = ['Character', options.gender, options.clothing, options.color, options.action].join('/') + '.png'

  if (src in imageCache) return imageCache[src]

  var image = imageCache[src] = document.createElement('img')
  image.src = src
    return image
}

var image = getCharacterImage({
  gender: 'male',
  color: 'white',
  clothing: 'plain',
  action: 'walking'
})

console.log(image.src)

ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100)
```

**Edit:** If you would prefer to cache images that have already been created, you can create a map from `src`s to images using dynamic object keys.

Comment: Isn't it better to define all the images first before using them?

Comment: You could; but whether that approach is "better" or not depends on whether you think all permutations of images are likely to be used in a given session.

Comment: Most likely not, but it's for a canvas game so I'd want to utilize ram and make the programming to be efficient. This code is beautiful, though I don't think it's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: I just added an image cache so an image is never created more than once for a particular `src` value. Let me know whether that works.